# Regex or str.replace for deleting some html tag

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a html box, AT BACK-END (PHP) where I need to delete everything that has `"font-family: dynamic values"`.

So, for example : 
`<p style="font-family:Georgia,serif"></p>` or `<p style="font-family:Georgia,serif;color:red"></p>`

and after `regexp` or `replace` it to be :
`<p> </p>` or `<p style='color:red'></p>`

Comment: Do you need to remove whole style tag from HTML tag?

Comment: @DarshanJain I need to delete everything that starts with `"font-family` and ends with closing `"` of font-family. Thanks.

Comment: Try this: $output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $input);

Comment: Is above expression work for you?

Comment: @DarshanJain it's working rege but he removes style attribute.
Thanks

Comment: Do not use Regex to parse HTML!  HTML is not regular and cannot be passed by a regular language.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`font-family *:[ \w,\-_]+;?`

it removes only `font-family` property from style attribute.
For demonstrations have a look [here](https://regexr.com/3mbso)